# Calcular el factorial de 10 utilizando un bucle while, una bifurcación if y una sentencia break

Tags: javascript, factorial

Quiero calcular el factorial de 10 utilizando un bucle while, una bifurcación if y una sentencia break.

Consigo obtener el factorial de 10 con el bucle while, pero ¿cómo puedo conseguirlo utilizando el if y la sentencia break?

```
let x = 10;
var i = x-1;


while(i > 1){
    x *= i;
    i--;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: ¿Es esto parte de algún ejercicio para familiarizarse con el lenguaje?

Comment: Sí, es un ejercicio de un curso JavaScript, y no entendía esta parte para qué sirve si con el while ya funciona correctamente. Supongo que es para familiarizarse. @PabloLozano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es invertir la condicion del while y usarala en un if al final de la iteracion, si se cumple ejecutamos el break, ahora para que el while se ejecute siempre debes poner como condicion o evaluacion algo que siempre de "True", en este caseo mientras que a x no se le pase un valor negativo este funcionaria como un true en una condicion.

debo resaltar que esto es una mala practica al programar.

```js
let x = 10;
var i = x-1;


while(x){
    x *= i;
    i--;
    if (i <= 1) break;
}
console.log(x);
```